# How to find rectangular region in a plot using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, rectangles

I have this attached plot drawn using x,y co-ordinates. How to identify nearly rectangular-shape region(s) in this plot (drawn in yellow manually for illustration purpose) using MATLAB?[image]

Comment: There are quite a few ways to approach this, you can select the coordinate on the plot, read them and calculate them (using simple euclidean distances and the area of square formula) or if you have some criteria to select the square, that would also be a possibility (i.e. -3dB cut-off .etc).

Comment: How do you determine the location of the rectangle based on the x,y plot?

Comment: @EdSmith: My question is how we can determine the location of nearly rectangular shape in the plot. The yellow rectangle (drawn for illustration purpose) is the final answer that i want to obtain.

Comment: I think this depends on the standard, in DSP, the 3dB cutt-off would be good as earlier said. If you are more into automatic control you may want to measure the distance between 10% of max and 90% of max. There may be more ways to do it as well. You should try to elaborate a bit more on this question. It is hard for us to tell what criteria is most appropriate.